# Android узнать имя пакета текущего открытого приложения?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть клавиатура, хочу в ней сделать проще шаринг.
Как бы в текущее приложение в котором нахожусь отправить Intent, а не выбирать из списка установленных.
Подобный код не совсем то, что нужно

```
mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, начиная с определенной версии (4.4 чтоли) невозможно получить список запущенных приложений.